# Degradation mechanism of hydroxymethylfurfural to 2,5-dioxo-3-hexenal and 4-oxopentanoic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

I want to understand the degradation mechanism of [hydroxymethylfurfural (HMF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroxymethylfurfural). According to the Wikipedia article, HMF is degraded in honey. Someone said that the degradation proceeds via **2** possible routes and that the products are 2,5-dioxo-3-hexenal and [4-oxopentanoic acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levulinic_acid).

What is the mechanism by which these compounds form? If you add a picture of the mechanism, it will be better.

Comment: I edited your question to improve the grammar. Let me know if I changed the meaning of your question.

Comment: As far as honey is concerned are you concerned more about the degradation of fructose into HMF (which can be a problem) or the degradation of HMF into other things?

Comment: @BenNorris Thank you for edit my question. But I'm concerned more about degradation of HMF to other things than degradation of fructose. But, can I add question about the fructose degradation in this question?

Comment: You can ask any question you want, but I would add the fructose question as a new question. It's better to have two separate questions than one question asking two things.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [link to a detailed reference on HMF](http://www.arkat-usa.org/get-file/20028/).  In section 3.3 (page 32) they show a mechanism for the acid catalyzed degradation of HMF.  As you noted, they do propose two pathways for decomposition, one leads to polymeric materials, the other leads to 2,5-dioxo-3-hexenal, which then can react further to produce 4-oxopentanoic acid. The work they describe was done by Horvat (Horvat, J.; Klaič, B.; Metelko, B.; Sunjic, V. Tetrahedron Lett. 1985, 26, 2111).

I don't want to reproduce their drawing, but follow the link and look for Scheme 17.  Most of the steps involve protonation of either

- a double bond to form a resonance stabilized carbocation followed by addition of water and elimination of a proton to yield an alcohol
- a hydroxyl group followed by elimination of water to yield a resonance stabilized carbocation followed by elimination of a proton to yield a double bond
- or protonation of the furan oxygen followed by ring opening to generate a protonated, resonance stabilized carbonyl

If you have any specific questions on the mechanism, just post back here.